# how to implement function createCookie within javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, popup

So I have this script (a countdown timer that closes the '#fb-popupdiv' div, when reaches to zero):

```
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var time = 11;
window.setInterval(test, 1000);
function test()
{
    time -=1;
    dom.query('#my_timer').html(time); 
    if(time == 0)        
    {
        dom.query('#fb-popupdiv').remove();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine with this?:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
   else var expires = "";
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);

    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}​
```

Let me explain. I'm making a likebox popup div, and I want the users who visit my site, see that popup only once in the day (so, they don't see it again and again visiting my site, several times). So I'm trying to figure a way to combine both scripts, to achieve that.

This is what i've got so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="fb-popupdiv">
<div id="fb-popup">
<h1 class="fb-title">To continue, click "Like" button</h1>
<p style="background:#fff;padding-bottom:20px;">
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBlindGuardianArgentina&amp;width=457&amp;height=263&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=false&amp;border_color=%23fff&amp;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:457px; height:263px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<span class="fb-closebutton">Or wait <span id="my_timer"></span> seconds.</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popupdiv{position:absolute;display:none;}
#fb-popupdiv{display:block;top:180px;left:278.5px;width:500px;height:355px;position:fixed;background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IHT1l.png');margin:0;overflow-y:auto;z-index:999999;text-align:center;border:10px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);border-radius:8px;}
#fb-popup{background-color:#fff;overflow:none;z-index:999999;height:227px;}
.fb-title{background:#6D84B4 none repeat scroll 0 0;border-top:1px solid #3B5998;border-left:1px solid #3B5998;border-right:1px solid #3B5998;color:white !important;padding:5px !important;margin:0 !important;font:normal 14px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif !important;}
.fb-closebutton{float:right;font:normal 11px/2.5em Arial, sans-serif !important;padding:5px 15px 20px 0;background:#fff;width:97%;text-align:right;color:#000 !important;}
#my-timer{width:400px;background:#fff; margin:0 auto;padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;}
```

Is it posible, or am I doing it all wrong?

I'm newbie, sorry.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Excuse my poor english.

Comment: Thanks for making the edits, Sheikh. I figured it out just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking more about how you would use your cookie code in order to display something only once a day.  Here's the basic logic for that.

Have this in your CSS so the popup is not visible by default:

```
#fb-popupdiv {display: none;}
```

Then, add this javascript:

```
dom.query(document).ready(function() {
    var val = readCookie("popupAlreadyShown");
    if (!val) {
        createCookie("popupAlreadyShown", 1, 1);
        // use your code here to show the popup here
        dom.query("#fb-popupdiv").show();
    } else {
        // popup was already shown less than 1 day ago
        // because cookie still exists
        // do anything else you might want to do here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @jfriend00, but here's the thing, the code to show the popup is HTML, not JavaScript, so maybe it's very difficult to achieve that. Should I post the entire code (CSS, HTML, Javascript) in another answer? Or maybe I'm not following you properly...

Comment: @user1903782 - Detecting a cookie on the client is done with javascript so you're going to HAVE to act via javascript to do what you want to do if you're doing it on the client.  You can create the HTML for the popup with javascript.  Or, you can have the HTML already in your page (defaulted to hidden) and show it with javascript.  "Popup" is such a generic term that without a lot more specifics about what exact HTML look you're trying to do, we can't really offer better advice.  Show us the HTML you're trying to achieve and we can be more specific.

Comment: Done. See the OP, please. And thanks again for your time. With all that code I can make the div '#fb-popupdiv' to close when countdown timer reaches to zero. It works well, but it loads everytime, what I'm looking for is any way to make it appear once in a day for a visitor, so he/she doesn't get bombed every time the reload the site.

Comment: @user1903782 - I added more specifics to my answer for how to make the popup visible only once a day.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, but still doesn't seem to work, though maybe I made some mistakes. This is what I did: 1) Replaced "display:block;" with "display:none;" for #fb-popupdiv. 2) Added that javascript after the first script in OP (the countdown timer) between "<script type="text/javascript"></script>". But now, the div doesn't appear at all (reloaded my IP to verify).

Comment: @user1903782 - I can't help you troubleshoot without seeing either a working copy of the code, a jsFiddle or the exact code you're using that I could put in a jsFiddle to test it.  Keep in mind that the code will only show the div once per day like you requested.  It also may be that you've undefined the symbol `jQuery` so you'll have to use your own synonym.  Did you check the JS error console to see what errors are showing?

Comment: Ok I added the code at Pastebin, so here it is: http://pastebin.com/pMEyrKYn. With all of that, the div doesn't load at all even when my IP changed (reconnected modem, also cleared cache and deleted cookies, ect). The JS error console throws an error which might be related: "Uncaught ReferenceError: readCookie is not defined"

Comment: @user1903782 - anytime you have a problem, you should first study what the error console says and fix all errors there.  I see several problems.  First, you have to include the `readCookie` and `setCookie` code.  Second, since you've undefined jQuery, you have to use `dom.query` instead (I've edited the code in my answer accordingly).

Comment: Yay! That did it! Thanks so much for your help and dedication, jfriend00! I modified createCookie to setCookie, and put everything in a single script tag. It works!! :D

Comment: @user1903782 - glad it's working for you.  Do you understand that on SO, if you get your question answered, you are supposed to select the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark one of the answers as the best answer?  That will indicate to the public which answer you thought was best, reward the person who provided the answer with some reputation points and you will earn some reputation points too for following the proper procedure.  After you earn some more reputation yourself, you can upvote any answer that helped you.

Comment: My bad I choose the other answer, sorry. Though I will earn some rep to bring yours up and to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin?

```
if (!$.cookie('daily_popup')) {
    // Code to show modal/popup; e.g. show_modal();
    $.cookie('daily_popup', 1, {expires: 1});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Wing Lian. No, I didn't tried it; saw it earlier, but I didn't know how to implement it. that's why I tried with function createCookie, with no luck, though.

Answer (score 1):

See the plugin:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You can then do:

```
$.cookie("test", 1);
```

To delete:

```
$.cookie("test", null);
```

Additionally, to set a timeout of a certain number of days (10 here) on the cookie:

```
$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 });
```

If the expires option is omitted, then the cookie becomes a session cookie, and is deleted when the browser exits.

To cover all the options:

```
$.cookie("test", 1, {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                           //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

   domain  : 'jquery.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                           //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                           //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                           //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

Comment: Thank you Palash, will check it out in a few minutes.